# listFiles() returns Null on Android 10

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-10.0

i want to build let's call it an 'mp3 player' app but weirdly, considering it has worked previously, but after doing some changes, i realised that i can no longer list files on external storage.

i have:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

and:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Library"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            >
```

log cat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.musire_v2, PID: 26911
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.musire_v2/com.example.musire_v2.Youtube}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object[].toString()' on a null object reference
```

Here is the library-activity code:

```
class Library : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.library)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)


        fun findSong(file: File): ArrayList<File> { //some code here }



        fun displaySongs() { //some code here }


        fun runtimePermission() {
            Dexter.withContext(this).withPermissions(
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            )
                .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
                    override fun onPermissionsChecked(multiplePermissionsReport: MultiplePermissionsReport) {
                        Log.d("TEST", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles().toString())
                        displaySongs()
                    }

                    override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                        list: List<PermissionRequest>,
                        permissionToken: PermissionToken
                    ) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest()
                    }
                }).check()
        }
        runtimePermission()
```

The line that causes the exception:
`Log.d("TEST",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles().toString)`

Comment: @blackapps added

Comment: I see no code that throws that exception. Please add the right code or indicate the line. Some code you posted twice. Why?

Comment: As a side note, please consider that [this method is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()). Also, other similar methods may return null if the external storage is unavailable. That being said, it looks like you're not getting null out of `getExternalStorageDirectory` but rather from `listFiles()`, which may indicate that the returned `File` is not a directory, or some IO error occurred.

Comment: What is your target SDK and device OS version? You might get this with SDK 30

Comment: @TuanChau yes target sdk is indeed 30, my OS version is 10. should I change something?

Comment: You can change the target SDK to 29 to be able to use the old way of file access. If this is not a required feature, [Document Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) is a better way. [MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files) is another thing you might want to check for Android OS 11+

Comment: @Joffrey indeed you are right, `getExternalStorageDirectory ` returns `/storage/emulated/0` which is a directory. Note: I recently cleaned the project and just rebooted before posting this question.

Comment: @blackapps fixed

Comment: @Joffrey thanks for all the info, sdk 29 didn't solve my problem tho.

Comment: listFiles() only returns null on an Android 10 device. Why didnt you conclude that? The solution has been posted a hundred times on stackoverflow. Why didnt you see/find that?

Comment: @blackapps my bad, it's beacause I realised my error was actually ```listFiles()``` not ```getExternalStorageDirectory  ```, is there anything I could do?

Comment: `listFiles() only returns null on an Android 10 device.`You are not reacting to my comment. Or confirm it.

Comment: @blackapps i confirm what you said. What's the alternative to list all the files in external storage for android 10+?

Comment: On an Android 11 device listFiles() will not return null. And for an Android 10 device i already stated: `The solution has been posted a hundred times on stackoverflow. Why didnt you see/find that?`

Comment: @blackapps Got it? thank you. I just saw one of your replies on the matter and it solved my problem. Have a good day.